# Como incluir versión framework 4.6.1 en una web API CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Buenas tengo un problema, he creado un aplicativo net core web api Vrs 2.1 y una biblioteca de clase netframework Vrs 4.6.1 y en esa biblioteca esta consumiendo un service reference y al momento de ejecutar el web api me sale un error de

> could not load file or assembly 'system.serviceModel',version=4.0.0 . Reference assemblies should not be loader for execution.they can only be loader in the reflection-only loader context

como la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he agregado en appsetting.json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Appsetting.js**

```
 {
    "Version":"1.0.0-*",
    "Dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
    },
    "Frameworks":{
    "netstandard1.6":{
    "Imports": "dnxcore50"
    },
    "dnx46":{}
    }

}
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar continua el mismo problema.

Lose que no esta permitido subir imagenes es que estoy en un servidor y a mi maquina local no lo puedo copiar.

Comment: Porfavor evitar usar imágenes, copia y pega la excepción y las settings, sino, por un lado complicado que alguien se tome el tiempo de mirar las imágenes, y peor aún el echo de que es más complicado encontrar la pregunta por las personas que tengan un problema parecido..

Comment: @juan salvador Portugal ya lo escribi el codigo que puse como imagen

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal ya lo escribi lo que puse

Comment: en tu projecto core agrega el la version del framework que la libreria que estas referenciando

Comment: @MiguelZarate como y donde lo agrego ? para que en mi netcore agregue framework , ya que como veras cuando hace referencia sale un error de como que no encuentra el framework 4.0 en el net core

Comment: Pudieras agregar una carpeta al bin de tu proyecto WebApiApplication1 para guardar la dll que genere tu ClassLibrary al hacer build y hacer referencia a la dll de tu bin, para hacer esto deberias agregar en las propiedades de tu ClassLibrary -> Build -> Output -> Output path -> Agregas la ruta de la carpeta donde guardarás tu dll en el bin de  tu WebApplication

Comment: @LordOfLies puedes responder como respuesta y los pasos po favo

Comment: Ya lo hice @PieroDev

Comment: @LordOfLies no funciono hermano sale el mismo erro

Comment: a ver si te entiendo, ¿quieres usar ASPnet Core con la API consumiendo una biblioteca hecha con .net "Full" Framework?

Comment: @fredyfx claro pero en esa biblioteca de clase estoy consumiendo de service reference de wcf

Comment: en ese caso, utiliza ASP.net MVC 5, con full framework, hasta donde tengo entendido, todavía no hay compatibilidad sobre lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Lo que sí hay es que usando una biblioteca de class hecha en Dot Net Core, se comunique con un servicio WCF y que dicha biblioteca se comunique con ASPnet Core. Revisa: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-1-0-0-and-asp-net-core-1-0-0-is-now-available/

Comment: Hola, debes elegir la versión del .NET framework de destino  a través del elemento TargetFramework. Ahí indicas la versión .NET Core y el Frameworks.   Incluso puedes compilar para varias plataformas de destino.  Echa un vistazo a https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Comment: @JoseDEV hermano puedes colocar como respuesta y como debería hacer.

Comment: Hola PieroDev, aquí está explicado paso a paso con imágenes, para poder elegir luego el framework https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/target-multiple-frameworks-in-aspnet-core2

Comment: @JoseDEV bueno al seguir esos pasos me salio un error en TargetFramework y ResolvePackageAssets